# reload component when change parts routing in angular

Tags: angular, routes, angular6, router, angular-routerlink

> I use angular 6.
>
> I have ListComponent which show list of products.

**my routing**

```
{
     path: ('list/:category/:subcategory'),
     component: ListComponent
}
```

**a tag**

```
<a class="link" [routerLink]="['/list/' + item.titleEn ]">
    {{ item.title }}
</a>

<a class="sub-link" [routerLink]="['/list/' + item.titleEn + '/' + itemSub.titleEn ]"
    {{ itemSub.title }}
</a>
```

now, when i click "/list/car/bmw" in HomeComponent (/home), that's worked and render ListComponent.
but when i click "/list/car/bmw" in ListComponent (/list/car/benz), that's not working and not render ListComponent.

Comment: Are you using `list/car/benz ` or `/list/car/benz ` ?

Comment: using /list/car/benz

Comment: What is the url you see on the browser with working routerLInk ?

Comment: routing are worked but component not render!

http://localhost:4200/list/Accessories
http://localhost:4200/list/food

when click food link component not render.

Comment: Try with routerLink `/fa/list/car/benz`

Comment: routing are worked but component not render! localhost:4200/list/Accessories localhost:4200/list/food when click food link component not render.

Comment: If you are using relatitve url then remove `/` from the begining from all the link or start with full path as `/fa/list/food`.

Comment: my bro, routing is correct worked.

but when change localhost:4200/list/Accessories to localhost:4200/list/food
ngOninit() not worked and not call...

Comment: my bro, routing is correct worked. but when change localhost:4200/list/Accessories to localhost:4200/list/food ngOnInit() not worked and not call

Comment: Looks like there are multiple issues in it. Create stackblitz demo, it will help to figure out the exact issues.

Comment: your comment not solve my ask but open my mind and I answered my ask...

my bro answer is: ActivatedRoute

thank you very much dear Sunil

Answer (score 3):

- When first  `"/list/car/bmw"` is loaded then angular got one paramerized route `"list/:category/:subcategory"` which matching the `"/list/car/bmw"` url. so it will render your component `ListComponent`.
- if by any action (button click or anchor click" if your url changed to `"/list/car/benz"` then it will not render `ListComponent`. As `ListComponent` is already loaded with parameterized route `'list/:category/:subcategory'`. **In this case route is not changing but the router params are changing**.

And to detect the param change Please use **ActivatedRoute** to check any change to the parameters.

**Step 1** - Do the constructor Injection of `ActivatedRoute`

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
   // Code snippet
   this.subscribeRouteChange();
}
```

Step 2 - Subscribe to for route param change

```
subscribeRouteChange() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params = {}) => {
        // Will log any change to the route.
        // You can add your own logic here
        console.log(params.category);
        console.log(params.subcategory)
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    this.router.navigate(['your path'])
  .then(() => {
    window.location.reload();
  });
```